# Database Diagrams inaccessible after change of Database name

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL server database which I recently renamed through SSMS.
The database works fine overall, except I can no longer access the Database Diagrams, or create new ones.  Whenever I attempt to do so, I get the following error message -

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

How can I regain access to the Database Diagrams, or at the very least, clear them and be able to create new ones again?

EDIT:  I've just noticed that Database Diagrams are not accessible in any of the databases in SQL server, not just the database that was renamed.

The full error message in SQL Server is as follows:

```
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DocumentObjectSite.QueryStatus(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.QueryStatus(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTrackSelectionExPrivate.Register()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConnectSelectionContext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.Activate()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.viewManager_ActiveViewChanged(Object sender, ActiveViewChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ExtensionMethods.RaiseEvent[TEventArgs](EventHandler`1 eventHandler, Object source, TEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Shell.ViewManager.SetActiveView(View view, ActivationType type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ShowInternal(ShowFlags showFlags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.<Show>b__26()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(Func`1 method)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.Show()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.MarshalingWindowFrame.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame.Show>b__7a()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.Invoke[TResult](Func`1 method)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.MarshalingWindowFrame.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame.Show()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.InvokeDesigner(IManagedConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolsMenuItemBase.MenuInvokedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Comment: Did you try renaming the database again, back to its old name? (Trying this now *might* make things worse.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution - hope this might help others . . .

You will need a second computer with either SQL Server and / or Visual Studio installed.  Then use the second computer to copy the .dll files specified in the steps below, and replace the corresponding files on the computer where the database diagrams is not working.

Step 1:
Replaced the following file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll

Step 2:
Replaced all files in the following folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\

I did this and all previous database diagrams are now working again.

Comment: Thanks for posting it. a year later, it helped me with the same issue. it works.